# Pass the value of radio button to another form using property

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I would appreciate if you guys read the whole question before marking it duplicate.

I trying to pass the value of radio button from one winform to another. It seemed quite simple but I couldn't figure it out yet. In Form1, I have two radio button controls named radioCapital, radioSmall and a button named btnInitialize.
The code behid the btnInitialize is as follows,

```
 public void btnInitialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (radioSmall.Checked)
        {
            radioSmall.Checked = true;
        }
        if (radioCapital.Checked)
        {
            radioCapital.Checked = true;
        }

        Form2 callForm2 = new Form2();
        callForm2.ShowDialog();

       
    }
```

And two properties, one for each radio button, which are suppose to return  boolean true if radio button is checked or false if not checked.

```
 public bool CapitalCheck
    {
        get
        {
            return this.radioCapital.Checked;
        }
    }
  
 public bool SmallCheck
    {
        get
        {
            return this.radioSmall.Checked;
             
        }
    }
```

Now in the second form which is Form2 I am trying to access both the properties and publishing their values in a lable control.

```
private void btnGetValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 initialize = new Form1();
        label3.Text = initialize.CapitalCheck.ToString() + " " + initialize.SmallCheck.ToString();
    }
```

I suppose to get one true and one false based on which radio button is checked. But it doesn't happen. Both the properties return false. I basically don't understand why.

Comment: You don't need `if` blocks in `btnInitialize_Click`. You are creating new object of Form1 in Form2. That's not the same as already opened Form1. So you will not get the values of the opened Form1.

Comment: You can create Boolean properties in Form2 and set them before opening it. `callForm2.SmallCheck = this.radioSmall.Checked;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set Form1 as the OWNER of Form2 by passing `this` to `ShowDialog()`:

```
Form2 callForm2 = new Form2();
callForm2.ShowDialog(this); // set Form1 as the OWNER
```

Then, in Form2, you can CAST `.Owner` back to Form1 and use it as expected:

```
private void btnGetValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 initialize = (Form1)this.Owner;
    label3.Text = initialize.CapitalCheck.ToString() + " " + initialize.SmallCheck.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, when you initialize Form2 you can just pass it in the constructor.
Example code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2(checkBox1.Checked);
            frm2.Show();
        }

public Form2(bool value)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = value.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I have testet passing it in the constructor and it worked. But i wanted it via property. Thanks.